# Sollten wir Übersetzungsfragen von Software-Programmierern beantworten?

Tags: discussion, answers

Recht häufig tauchen hier Fragen auf, bei denen Leute, die mit dem Programmieren oder landessprachlich Anpassen von Computerprogrammen beschäftigt sind, wissen wollen, wie sie diesen oder jenen Begriff in der deutschen Version ihrer Software wiedergeben sollen. Typischerweise wird nach Begriffen zur Beschriftung von Buttons gefragt, etwa für

> - Go
> - Submit
> - Cancel
> - Next

und so weiter.

Die Fragen sind oft eingigermaßen so formuliert, dass man den Fragestellern unterstellen kann, sie hätten sich vorher ein bisschen kundig gemacht (na ja... mit Google Translate eben...).

Trotzdem habe ich bei solchen Fragen immer das blöde Gefühl: Da verrichtet einer eine kommerzielle Arbeit, die in der Regel auch ganz gut bezahlt ist, und anstatt für seine Übersetzungsdinge einen professionellen Übersetzer zu engagieren (der ja seine Familie auch ernähren möchte), bedient er sich kostenlos bei dem hier versammelten kulturellen Wissen.

Noch dazu sind die Fragen in der Regel nicht als solche schon so interessant, dass man sie als Bereicherung der Sammlung hier ansehen würde.

Ich tendiere also dazu, solche Anfragen mehr oder weniger höflich mit

> For questions of this type I recommend hiring a professional translator. You can find good freelancers on platforms such as www.proz.com

zu kommentieren.

Würdet ihr dies als eine allgemeine Verhaltensregel begrüßen?

---

Beispiele

- [Best words to notify that something is being sent in a web form](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47030/best-words-to-notify-that-something-is-being-sent-in-a-web-form)

Comment: Interessieren würde mich, warum jemand die Frage beminussenswürdig findet.

Comment: Auf Meta (überall auf den ganzen SE Meta-Seiten!) bedeuten die Votes Zustimmung (+1) Ablehnung (-1) Egal (0). Du bekommst ja deshalb auch keine Reputationspunkte. -1 heißt hier übersetzt, dass ich dagegen bin, solche Fragen pauschal abzuschießen, und schon gar nicht mit diesem Kommentar (stell dir nur vor, ein solcher professioneller Übersetzer stellt hier eine Frage, der kommt nie wieder).

Comment: @Takkat Ich finde es aber auch seltsam, dass durch dieses Voting die Fragestellung oder das Thema an sich als blöd bewertet wird (not useful). "Zustimmung" kann man dann ja immer noch bei den unterschiedlichen Antworten bekunden. Daher: die Frage zu stellen, halte ich für sinnvoll, den vorgeschlagenen Modus in der Frage aber ebenfalls nicht. Die Frage bekommt also einen +1 von mir.

Comment: @LangLangC: Wenn du an dem Pop-Up "not useful" etwas ändern willst solltest du das auf [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) diskutieren. Eine Meta-Frage mit einem Upvote zu versehen, die man zwar prinzipiell gut findet, mit deren Inhalt man aber nicht einverstanden ist, führt dazu, dass wir keine Community-Abstimmung haben. Es ist viel besser, man stellt eine offene Frage und gibt dazu die Antwort, die man sich wünscht, separat. So gesehen kann man eine Meta-Frage, die sich selbst beantwortet schon als *not useful* sehen, auch wenn die Frage an sich berechtigt ist.

Comment: @Takkat  Die Plus- und Minuspunkte bei den Fragen als Instrument zur *Beantwortung* der Frage zu verwenden (+ = ja, - = nein), funktioniert aber nur bei Ja-Nein-Fragen wie bei dieser meiner hier. Viele Fragen sind aber "Wie"-Fragen (siehe gleich die nächste in chronologischer Folge), die man nicht mit Ja und Nein beantworten kann. Was machst du dann mit Plus und Minus? Du drückst aus, dass du die Frage interessant findest. Warum nun diese Ungleichbehandlung?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Wenn Du eine Meta-Frage mit einer eigenen Ansicht zur Abstimmung startest, dann dienen die +/- Votes genau dazu. Andernfalls musst du die Frage ergebnisoffen formulieren und eine entsprechende Antwort schreiben. Das geht natürlich auch.

Comment: @Takkat Bezüglich der Voting diskussion hier, möchte ich hier auf die [Help-page](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) verweisen, wo steht ` On posts tagged [meta-tag:feature-request], voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.`. Dein letzter Kommentar beschreibt ja doch ziemlich genau das, aber ohne den [meta-tag:feature-request] zu erwähnen.

Comment: @Cashbee: es ist hier ja kein "feature request" - dennoch sind Votes auf Meta genau so gedacht.

Answer (score 10):

Ich denke, solche Fragen unterscheiden sich nicht von anderen Fragen, in denen wir um Korrekturlesen oder Übersetzen gefragt werden.

Also sobald es sich um einen längeren, individuellen Text handelt: *close as proofreading/translation request*

Das ist völlig anders, wenn es nur um einzelne Wörter oder Fragen nach einer genauen Bezeichnung geht. Bei den wenigen Fragen, die wir zu diesem Thema haben, sollen wir nie ein komplettes User-Interface übersetzen, sondern es wird um unser Urteil zu einer geschickte Formulierung meist eines einzelnen Vorgangs gefragt. Das können wir natürlich sehr gut, da traditionell auf StackExchange ein guter Teil unserer Leute einen EDV-Hintergrund haben.

Wer weiß, vielleicht war der Fragesteller sogar ein professionell engagierter Übersetzer? Und für genau diese Leute wollen wir da sein.

**Natürlich sollen Professionelle hier eine Antwort finden!**

Aber auch ein Gelegenheitsprogrammierer, der sich einen Übersetzer gar nicht leisten kann, ist willkommen, wenn er bei uns um eine Antwort bittet. EDV-Fragen sorgen immerhin für gewaltigen Traffic und sind netzwerk-weit sehr beliebt. Und es sind genau solche Fragen, die den Besuchern unserer Seite auch in Zukunft helfen werden. Wieso sollte man auf einer StackExchange-Seite keine Fragen zur EDV-Terminologie stellen dürfen? Das lässt sich nicht vermitteln.

Ich bin also dafür, dass wir Fragen zur EDV-Terminologie und einem deutschen Nutzerinterface gerne beantworten. Nur so können wir dem hohen Anspruch unserer Seite gerecht werden, den wir hoffentlich noch haben.

Comment: Beachtenswert würde ich es auch finden, dass zwar einerseits ein Unbehagen sich auch bei mir einstellt, bezahlten Profis Arbeit entgeltfrei abzunehmen, aber gerade sehr deutlich an solchen kurzen Beispielen wie oben, dies keinesfalls ersichtlich ist. Und erst recht nicht überprüfbar. Denn ein kleines FOSS-(Hobby-)projekt verdient bestimmt mehr Unterstützung als ein entlohnter Lazybones?

Comment: @LangLangC: genau, denn mit kurzen Schnipseln nehmen wir keinem Profi das Brot weg und ein ganzes kommerzielles Projekt akzeptieren wir sowieso nicht.

Comment: Ich bin in einem bestimmten Teilgebiet der Elektrotechnik Profi und in einem bestimmten Teilgebiet der EDV. In allen anderen Gebieten muss ich mir jemanden suchen, der es besser weiß, sobald ich mit meinem Latein am Ende bin. Und das heißt bereits, dass ich in das Standardwerk reingeguckt habe und meine Frage dort auch nicht beantwortet finde. Die richtigen Bücher kennt auch nur jemand, der Spezialist ist. Genau dafür ist StackExchange doch da, wenn ich das richtig verstanden hab.

Comment: Zum Thema kommerzielle Verwertung und "Faulheit". Es ist andersherum. Mit Antworten hier kann man Geschäftsbeziehungen begründen. Es ist mir nun schon mehrmals passiert, dass ich aufgrund von irgendwo beantworteten Fragen (schließt Usenet, Mailinglisten etc. ein) angesprochen wurde, ob ich nicht gegen Bezahlung helfen könne. Jobangebote kommen so durchschnittlich ein bis zweimal im Jahr.